# Prove that at most one man obtains his worst choice in stable matching algorithm

Tags: matching-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

For the Stable Matching algorithm by Gale-Shapley, how do I prove that at most one man will get his worst choice?

My intuition is that I have to use contradiction. Assume that there are two men who will get their worst preferences: $M_1$ with $W_1$ and $M_2$ with $W_2$. I have to prove $M_2$ and $W_2$ are unstable. However, I can't think of anything. Can anyone help me with the proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $M_1$'s last choice is $W_1$ and $M_2$'s last choice is $W_2$. Before they are forced to select $W_1$/$W_2$ respectively, the Gale–Shapley algorithm has already directed $M_1$/$M_2$ to propose to all women other than $W_1$/$W_2$. Thus all women have been proposed to, so are now engaged, so the algorithm stops. But we assumed that the algorithm *does not* stop here, so we have a contradiction and at most one man can have his worst choice.

Comment: I really don't understand. Where is the part "at most one man" proved?

Comment: @Jordan If I can find two men who are matched to their worst choices - so _not_ at most one man - my answer shows that it can't happen. If there is at most one such man I cannot do anything.

Comment: @Jordan You can accept my answer now.

Comment: Could you say more precisely what you mean by "the best possible matching for each man"?

Comment: @stewbasic It means "each man gets his best possible choice among all stable matchings".

Comment: I see, thanks. So it's important in your proof that the new matching is still stable.

Comment: The deferred acceptance algorithm produces the *stable* matching which is Pareto optimal for the men, not the matching that is the *best possible for each man*.

Comment: @stewbasic Answer edited. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment which mixed up the stable condition. We don't know how $W_1$ ranks $M_1$ vs $M_2$, so I don't see why the women all get better matchings. I also still don't see why $M_1W_2$, $M_2W_1$ is necessarily stable.

Comment: If you are directly proving the original matching was not stable, then the observation "each man gets his best possible choice among all stable matchings" is not relevant. But for this you would need to show $W_2$ prefers $M_1$ over $M_2$,

Comment: @stewbasic Stability of the modified matching doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that we assumed the _original_ matching to be stable and having two men matched to their worst choices. Since a contradiction was derived and Gale-Shapley always produces a stable matching, the result follows.

Comment: @stewbasic Well, how would you go about solving the question?

Comment: I added an answer with an alternate argument. After your latest edit I think you are arguing that "worst possible matching for each woman among all stable matchings" implies $W_1$ prefers $M_2$ over $M_1$, but again I don't see how this follows a priori. For example, if each person is the first preference of their first preference, then GS assigns each woman their first preference.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: I can't accept the answer. I don't see how you're proving a contradiction. You chose a specific case in which M1 's last choice is W1 and M2's last choice is W2, and pair M1-W2 && M2-W1. I don't see how this is generalizable, bc there can be another different pairing. Also this is not a contradiction. It should have been M1 is paired with last choice W1 and M2 is with W2, and you prove that this is a contradiction of the algorithm

Comment: @Jordan OK, you can do it now.

Comment: Thanks I get it now!! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the basic setup as described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Shapley_algorithm) (ie equal numbers of men and women, strict preferences). Assume $M_1$ and $M_2$ are paired with their worst choices, $W_1$ and $W_2$, respectively. Observe the following:

1. $M_1$ must propose to every woman over the course of the algorithm, proposing to $W_1$ last.
2. $M_1$ makes at most one proposal per round.
3. Once a woman is proposed to, they remain engaged for the rest of the algorithm (though maybe not to the same person).

Consider the state just before the final round. By 1 and 2, $M_1$ has proposed to each woman other than $W_1$ (and possibly $W_1$ also), and similarly for $M_2$. Thus every woman has been proposed to, so by 3 they are all engaged. We have assumed equal numbers of men and women, so the men are also all engaged. But this means the algorithm should terminate, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence: "assume equal number of men and women". How does that say that the last two men are already engaged, which results in a contradiction?

Comment: @Jordan Each man can only be engaged to one woman. So if all $n$ women are engaged, then all $n$ men must also be engaged.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all men have the same preferences and are indifferent over all women. In any stable match, any man who matches gets his worst choice.

Suppose all the men have strict preferences. Suppose there are $K$ men and $K+1$ women.  All men rank the same woman last, but all women and all men find one another acceptable.  None of the men get their worst choice in the outcome of the GS algorithm with the men proposing and the claim is false.

Comment: This is only an example and does not answer the question.

Comment: It disproves your claim. I have exhibited a profile of preferences for which it is false. You need to add an assumption of strictness of the men's preferences and then play with Conway's lattice theorem to get anything close to what you want.

Comment: It is assumed in Gale-Shapley that all men's preferences are strict.

Comment: There are thousands of papers on stable matching and the deferred acceptance algorithm written since GS 1962 that do not assume strictness. If you want a 1962 answer be more specific.

Comment: Then your answer doesn't belong here. Your claim also disproves _the question that is being asked here_, and as such you are talking about generalised stable matching, which is not under the scope of Gale-Shapley. Your example just shows that assuming total indifference leads to trivial things - any man who matches also gets his _best choice_, and there is nothing to say.

Comment: Preference profiles with indifferences are admissible to the GS algorithm, and that is an identification strategy for important empirical work because it creates the possibility of random tie-breaking. Let me put it another way: you need to refine your question in order for it to be tight enough to make sense. What do you want to assume about the space of admissible preferences?

Comment: The question already assumes strict preferences - you have just shown that. You have given the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: The GS algorithm maps profiles of preferences to matchings. It makes no assumption about the domain of preferences. GS say that for convenience they'll assume no ties, but again, it isn't 1962: the algorithm itself makes no restrictions on the domain of admissible preferences, and you asked about the algorithm, not the paper.

Comment: The 1962 version that assumes strict preferences is what I learned in my CS4261 Algorithmic Mechanism Design class at the National University of Singapore, and I suppose this is the same at other universities, and thus I presume this is the context of this question. Once again, I say you are answering the wrong question. You have shown that the question's claim is false _if_ you drop strictness, but you have not shown that it is true otherwise.

Comment: Why would anyone --- ever, in a million years --- care where you took a class?

Comment: It is just background information.

Comment: @Renard perhaps it would be more productive to propose an edit to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Let us begin by supposing that there are n men and n women, meaning there are n men ranking n women and vice versa. Let man x = Mx and woman x = Wx. Let us also assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there are two men M1 and M2 who have both been paired with their least-preferred choices, W1 and W2 respectively.

If we examine how M1 could have been paired with W1 (his least-preferred choice), we must recognize that this means that M1 had proposed to every other woman and had gotten rejected. M1 must have gotten rejected by every other woman because every other woman had to already have been
paired with a man that she preferred to M1, by construction of the Gale-Shapley algorithm.

If every other woman had already been paired with a man that she had preferred to M1, that means that every other man besides M1 was also paired. So, once M1 was paired with it’s least-preferred woman W1, all women and men would have been paired. By construction of the Gale-Shapley algorithm, the algorithm’s terminating condition would have been met, namely that
all women and men are paired, and the algorithm would stop running.

What this suggests is that Gale-Shapley would have already terminated execution before M2 even had the chance to be paired with W2 (its least-preferred choice), which contradicts our initial assumption that M1 and M2 were both paired with their least-preferred choices. This assumes,
however, that M2 and W2 were not already paired. But, how can we be certain that M2 and W2 had not already been paired?

Well, the answer is, for the same reason we know that execution must stop once M1 is paired with W1. As we have established, when M1 pairs with its least-preferred choice W1, execution must stop because all men and women would have been matched by then. Therefore, we can be certain that M2 could not have been matched with W2 because that would not allow M1 to match
with W1 in the first place; the algorithm’s execution would have terminated.

So, our contradiction stands, and we have proven that there is at most one man who gets their last choice.